# Как дождаться элемента?

Tags: javascript, selenium

сейчас выдает

> NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".elem"}

```js
await btn.click();
const elem = driver.findElement(By.css('.elem'))
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке, в струкруте DOM-а не существует элемента с селектором `.elem` (По крайней мере в тот момент как вы ищите). Возможно вам стоит добавить структуру документа в вопрос, а мы вам поможем написать селектор (не забудьте указать элемент который вы собираетесь выбрать).

Answer (score 0):

В JavaScript с использованием Selenium можно использовать методы явного и неявного ожидания из библиотеки, WebDriverIO или Protractor.
Как пример:

```
const { browser, $, $$ } = require('webdriverio');

// Ожидание появления элемента с селектором "#my_element" в течение 10 секунд
const element = await $('#my_element');
await element.waitForExist({ timeout: 10000 });

// Продолжение выполнения тестового сценария после успешного ожидания
```